# How to remove inbox label of gmail messages using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to remove inbox label from gmail messages using google script?[You can refer the link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#removelabellabel)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is: you can archive threads using `moveToArchive()`. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#moveToArchive()) the documentation.